# Does Multisig have any privacy drawbacks?

Tags: privacy, multisig

Does implementing multisig at the protocol level raise any privacy concerns? In other words, because several people are now involved in a trx, does that raise the probabilities of de-anonymizing the trx? If you know lets say that 4 people were involved in a transaction, does that make it 4x easier to trace the transaction? Or if you know that someone uses multisig at a particular exchange, can you use that fact to narrow down the pool of possible trxs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Monero multisig addresses look and work exactly the same as any other Monero address, and so do transactions. All the "magic" is done off-chain between the wallets involved. The reason that multisig has not been implemented pre-RCT is because the work would have been wasted since non-RCT transactions are becoming obsolete.

Bytecoin, Monero's predecessor implemented multisig (or at least had a documented method for implementing multisig), but it was completely absent any privacy measures so all amounts and so on could be easily deduced as it could not be used without mixin = 0. Ring signatures (together with CT) on the other hand enables the same degree of privacy regardless of whether it is multisig or not. Multisig transactions should be indistinguishable from a normal transaction on the blockchain.

Comment: So with RingCT we will (theoretically) be able to use any mixin level for multisig trxs and they will be indistinguishable from normal trxs, or will the absence of amounts on the blockchain be the only privacy factor for multisig?

Comment: They'll be indistinguishable. Stealth addresses will ensure that no address will be indentifiable as being part of a multisig transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not 100% clear here. Will multisig txs have full RingCT privacy functionality or will they rely only on stealth addresses for privacy (while mixin remains 0 and amounts are public? You said in your original answer that RingCT would enable privacy for multisig, but then above it seems like stealth is the only privacy factor.

Comment: My response is too long, so I'll add an edit above.

Comment: Whoah, looking back at this I see it's total BS (sorry). Monero multisig addresses are exactly the same to an outside observer and so are the TX-es. It could work with non-RCT, too! I think we were waiting for RCT just to avoid the double job - to first implement it for non-RCT, only to have it become obsolete and do it all over again for RCT. @ferretinjapan If you don't mind, I'd like to edit out the nonsense :)